Godot 4.1 Meshes Don't Render on Top of Each Other
I'm using a combination of a simple noise terrain generator and water shader mesh to try and get the effect of islands and some water, but when I try and put the water shader at y=0 so that it will make an ocean around the islands, they render strangely and the water shader only renders when not looked at with the terrain behind it.
(The strange effect can be seen around the corners of the map)
Terrain .gd script:
extends Node3D

var size = 256

func _ready():
    generate_island()

func generate_island():
    randomize()
    
    var surface_tool = SurfaceTool.new()
    var data_tool = MeshDataTool.new()
    var noise = FastNoiseLite.new()
    
    # Mesh settings
    var plane_mesh = PlaneMesh.new()
    plane_mesh.size = Vector2(size, size)
    plane_mesh.center_offset = Vector3(0,0,0)
    plane_mesh.subdivide_depth = size / 8
    plane_mesh.subdivide_width = size / 8 
    
    # Noise settings
    noise.frequency = 0.015
    noise.fractal_lacunarity = 0.5
    noise.seed = randi_range(0,9999999999)
    noise.noise_type = FastNoiseLite.TYPE_SIMPLEX_SMOOTH
    
    surface_tool.create_from(plane_mesh, 0)
    var array_mesh = surface_tool.commit()
    data_tool.create_from_surface(array_mesh, 0)
    
    for i in range(data_tool.get_vertex_count()):
        var vertex = data_tool.get_vertex(i)
        var value = noise.get_noise_3d(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z)
        
        # Total scale of the terrain
        vertex.y = value * 50
        
        data_tool.set_vertex(i, vertex)
    
    for s in range(array_mesh.get_surface_count()):
        array_mesh.clear_surfaces()
    
    data_tool.commit_to_surface(array_mesh)
    surface_tool.begin(Mesh.PRIMITIVE_TRIANGLES)
    surface_tool.create_from(array_mesh, 0)
    surface_tool.generate_normals()
    
    var material = StandardMaterial3D.new()
    material.albedo_color = Color(0.2,0.4,0.2,1)
    
    var mesh_instance = MeshInstance3D.new()
    mesh_instance.mesh = surface_tool.commit()
    mesh_instance.set_surface_override_material(0, load("res://Materials/ground_material.tres"))
    mesh_instance.create_trimesh_collision()
    
    $IslandTerrain.add_child(mesh_instance)

Water Shader .gd script
shader_type spatial;

uniform float metallic : hint_range(0.0, 1.0) = 0.6;
uniform float specular : hint_range(0.0, 1.0) = 0.5;
uniform float roughness : hint_range(0.0, 1.0) = 0.6;
uniform vec4 out_color : source_color = vec4(0.6, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8);
uniform float amount : hint_range(0.2, 1.5) = 0.8;
uniform float beer_factor = 0.2;
uniform sampler2D depth_texture : source_color, hint_depth_texture;

float generateOffset(float x, float z, float val1, float val2, float time){
    float speed = 1.0;
    
    float radiansX = ((mod(x + z * x * val1, amount) / amount) + (time * speed) * mod(x * 0.8 + z, 1.5)) * 2.0 * 3.14;
    float radiansZ = ((mod(val2 * (z * x + x * z), amount) / amount) + (time * speed) * 2.0 * mod(x, 2.0)) * 2.0 * 3.14;
    
    return amount * 0.5 * (sin(radiansZ) + cos(radiansX));
}

vec3 applyDistortion(vec3 vertex, float time){
    float xd = generateOffset(vertex.x, vertex.z, 0.2, 0.1, time);
    float yd = generateOffset(vertex.x, vertex.z, 0.1, 0.3, time);
    float zd = generateOffset(vertex.x, vertex.z, 0.15, 0.2, time);
    return vertex + vec3(xd, yd, zd);
}

void vertex() {
    VERTEX = applyDistortion(VERTEX, TIME * 0.1);
}

void fragment() {
    NORMAL = normalize(cross(dFdx(VERTEX), dFdy(VERTEX)));
    METALLIC = metallic;
    SPECULAR = specular;
    ROUGHNESS = roughness;
    ALBEDO = out_color.xyz;
    
    float depth = texture(depth_texture, SCREEN_UV).r;
    depth = depth * 2.0 - 1.0;
    depth = PROJECTION_MATRIX[3][2] / (depth + PROJECTION_MATRIX[2][2]);
    depth = depth + VERTEX.z;
    
    depth = exp(-depth * beer_factor);
    ALPHA = clamp(1.0 - depth, 0.0, 1.0);
}

